# Error HY093 with a MySQL Insert PDO Request

Tags: php, pdo

After reading all others questions about the HY093, I open this one to figure out why I've got this message too.

Here is my table :
[image: Table PhpMyAdmin screenshot]

And here is my request :
(Where $conn is my PDO connection)

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Sites (Email,URL,Title,Description,PageRank,Rewrite,MetaDesc,Origin,BackLink,nbBackLink,RssTitle,RssAddress,SocAddress,SocPostalCode,SocCity,SocCountry,SocTel,Offer,Status,nbHit)
                         VALUES (:Email,:URL,:Title,:Description,:PageRank,:Rewrite,:MetaDesc,:Origin,:BackLink,0,:RssTitle,:RssAddress,:SocAddress,:SocPostalCode,:SocCity,:SocCountry,:SocTel,:Offer,:Status,0)");
$sql->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$pageRank = new GooglePageRank($_POST["site_url"]);

$sql->bindParam(":Email",$_POST["submail"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":URL",$_POST["site_url"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":Title",$_POST["site_title"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":Description",$_POST["site_desc"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":PageRank",$pageRank->PageRank,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(":Rewrite",stringToRewrite($_POST["site_title"]),PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":MetaDesc",$_POST["site_desc"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":Origin",$_POST["site_country"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":BackLink",$_POST["site_backlink"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":RssTitle",$_POST["site_rss_title"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":RssAddress",$_POST["site_rss_addr"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":SocAddress",$_POST["soc_addr"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":SocPostalCode",$_POST["soc_cp"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":SocCity",$_POST["soc_city"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":SocCoutry",$_POST["soc_pays"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":SocTel",$_POST["soc_tel"],PDO::PARAM_STR);

$offer = $_POST["offer"] == "premium" ? 1 : 0;
$status = $_POST["offer"] == "premium" ? 2 : 0;

$sql->bindParam(":Offer",$offer,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(":Status",$status,PDO::PARAM_INT);

$sql->execute();
var_dump($sql->errorInfo());
var_dump($sql->errorCode());
```

Any idea why I keep have an HY093 error?

Comment: sure. number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: This wasn't that. Aynber found why ;)

Comment: That was **exact** error. There are no :SocCoutry token in the query, means number does not match

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have a typo in one of your bindParams, which means you have a mismatch in parameters:

```
$sql->bindParam(":SocCoutry",$_POST["soc_pays"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

should be

```
$sql->bindParam(":SocCountry",$_POST["soc_pays"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: I encountered the same problem. And It's already cost me lots of time for finding out the mistake in my code. Still looking for ...

Comment: @LCB It's probably a typo somewhere, but you can create a new question. A fresh pair of eyes may help.

Comment: Just chased my tail for a hour before finding one of my parameter names had a " " at the end... I'd checked for typos but didn't pick up the space.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an interesting case I found:

Running this query:

```
INSERT INTO videosubmissions (member_login, submission_date) VALUES (":login", ":submission-date")
```

Bound with:

```
[ ':login',           $info['login'],   PDO::PARAM_STR ],
[ ':submission-date', $submission_date, PDO::PARAM_STR ]
```

works... but

```
INSERT INTO videosubmissions (member_login, submission_date) VALUES (:login, :submission-date)
```

fails with an HY093 error.
I suspected this was caused by the implicit conversion from string to date but trying an explicit STR_TO_DATE(format, sDate) didn't fix it.
However if I quote all my placeholders in other queries with PDO::PARAM_STR value, it caused problems.

I know this doesn't really answer the Q but it adds another case to the mix to help figure out what's up.

Comment: Interestingly, manually substituting the strings in the query and running on MyPhpAdmin works as well.

Comment: i have somewhat same issue, i found that if the var-array contain more entries then the query expect, then HY093 happens

Answer (score 0):

My issue was number of parameters didn't match number of placeholders. Might be worth adding this to @aynber's answer