# Why this Query returns always HY093 Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

My Query return always the Mysql HY093 error but why?
I have all parameters and still its not working...

Can someone help ?

```
// create PDO params array
$params = [
    ':employee '    => $formData['employee'],
    ':usedFrom'     => $formData['usedFrom'],
    ':usedTill'     => $formData['usedTill'],
    ':company'      => $formData['company'],
    ':costCenter'   => $formData['costCenter'],
    ':vehicle'      => $formData['vehicle'],
    ':vehicleTag'   => $formData['vehicleTag'],
    ':updatedAt'    => $formData['updatedAt'],
    ':ID'           => $formData['ID']
];

// update entry
$return = $db->pquery(
    'UPDATE entry SET employee_id = :employee, used_from = :usedFrom, used_till = :usedTill, company_id = :company, cost_center_id = :costCenter, vehicle_id = :vehicle, vehicle_tag = :vehicleTag, updated_at = :updatedAt WHERE ID = :ID',
    $params
);
```

Comment: What is `pquery` function?

Comment: `':employee '` should probably be `':employee'` (no space)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error HY093 with a MySQL Insert PDO Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027112/error-hy093-with-a-mysql-insert-pdo-request)