# Error HY093 on executing INSERT into table

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo

[image: SQL table]
This is the table where I´m trying to the the insert.

When i try to make a insert using pdo I get the following error:

> Array ( [0] => HY093 [1] => [2] => )

All of the information comes from a html form.

The connection to the `db` is working because before I do this insert I do a fetch so that's not the problem.

I already checked all the variables with echo and they are correct.

Also tried to add the column 'id' to the *sql*, and give it the value `NULL`, but the error is the same as the above. 
But since the column '`id`' is auto incremented i didn't put it in the sql. See my code above to understand what I did.

```
$nome = $_POST['name'];
$mail = $_POST['email'];
$psw = $_POST['pass'];
$ni = $_POST['nif'];
```

This two variables comes from a fetch, and it works. They are only here because the belong to the Insert statement.

```
$roleid = $row['id'];
$rolen = $row['nome'];    

$sql = "INSERT INTO users ( nome, email, psw, nif, role_id, role_name)
VALUES ( :nome, :mail, :psw, :ni, :roleid, :rolen)";


$stmt = $db1->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue('nome', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('email', $mail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('psw', $psw, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('nif', $ni, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue('role_id', $roleid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue('role_name', $rolen, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$error = $stmt->errorInfo();
print_r($error);
```

Executing this insert I get the following error:

> Array ( [0] => HY093 [1] => [2] => )

Comment: "For a prepared statement using named placeholders, this will be a parameter name of the form :name. For a prepared statement using question mark placeholders, this will be the 1-indexed position of the parameter." So please try to change your bindValue first arguments to contain ":". It also would be nice to see the db table structure to make sure you have not done any mistakes with column names

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error HY093 with a MySQL Insert PDO Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027112/error-hy093-with-a-mysql-insert-pdo-request)

Comment: You need `:email` instead of `:mail`

Comment: You also haven't stated where, and how, `$row` is defined and populated.

Comment: @ViktarPryshchepa I added ":" to the first argument in every bind value but the error is the same `Array ( [0] => HY093 [1] => [2] => )`. Also inserted an image of the table structure.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i need `:mail` because that's the name of the variable as you can see `$mail = $_POST['email'];`

Comment: `NIF` and `nif`.

Comment: @AndyG this `$row` comes from a `fetch()` I do before the insert and it works so i didnt put the code in the question, just the name of the variable

Comment: @LuisLuisMaiaMaia You can call the parameter as you like. But you must use the same name in `bindValue()`.

Comment: As @PaulSpiegel noticed, you should fix all your `bindValue` calls. You obviously __don't understand__ that placeholder will be replaced with binded value. So, for example, if you have `roleid` placeholder, but bind `role_id` - it __will not work__.

Comment: @LuisLuisMaiaMaia you have param `:mail`, but binding to param `email`. change binding to 'mail', right here `$stmt->bindValue('email', $mail, PDO::PARAM_STR);`. param and binding argument should be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution to the question, I wasn't using the same name in the `bindValue()` function

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$psw = $_POST['psw'];
$nif = $_POST['nif'];
$roleid = $row['id'];
$rolen = $row['nome'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO users ( nome, email, psw, nif, role_id, role_name)
        VALUES ( :name, :email, :psw, :nif, :roleid, :rolen)";

$stmt = $db1->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':psw', $psw, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':nif', $nif, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':roleid', $roleid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':rolen', $rolen, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```